# System.IO dont create the file json

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.io.file

System.IO dont not create the file with save game.
I try to run unity in adminstrator mode, and nothing.

**Debug Log:**

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "C:\Users\HP\AppData\LocalLow\NameName\BeautyGame\gamesettings.json"
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options, System.String msgPath, System.Boolean bFromProxy, System.Boolean useLongPath, System.Boolean checkHost) (at <ac823e2bb42b41bda67924a45a0173c3>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions,string,bool,bool,bool)
```

And code:

```cs
string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(gameSettings, true);
File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/gamesettings.json", jsonData));
```

Comment: Two things: (1) Note that the error message says: _Could not find file **"C:\Users\HP\AppData\LocalLow\NameName\BeautyGame\gamesettings.json"**_. Pay attention to the full file path mentioned here. (2) Note that the stack trace you posted is incomplete. Thus, a work item for you: Check whether `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` appears in the full stack trace. Personally, i doubt that the File.WriteAllText code line you have shown here caused this specific "_Could not find file_" error. Check your project for other places in your code where the gamesettings.json file is being access in whatever way

Comment: P.S. If the stacktrace is not incomplete as i assumed, check the `InnerException` property of the exception you got. It could perhaps contain another exception object whose error message and stacktrace could reveal more helpful information...

Comment: I tried all these things. Nothing helps me. Maybe there is something other than "System.IO"?
It will be so easier for me. I will add that this is my first contact with the unit. I know that it is stupid, but I do not know any other programming language than through LARGE projects. Greetings.

Comment: Does that folder actually exist?

Comment: Also, consider using `File.WriteAllText(Path.Join(Application.persistentDataPath, "gamesettings.json"), jsonData));`

Comment: Nope this not working.

Comment: Please update your question to show a screenshot of a command prompt. That command prompt must have a visible current directory of `C:\Users\HP\AppData\LocalLow\NameName\BeautyGame\ ` It must have a `dir` run such that we can see the json file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to rather use `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` and make sure the `FileMode.Create` is set. Also create the folder if it doesn't exist.

```
var folderPath = Application.persistentDataPath;

// Create directory if not exists
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}
```

Than use `Path.Combine` to crate path strings that are system independent

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "gamesettings.json");
```

now write the file

```
// Create file or overwrite if exists
using (var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(content);
    }
}
```

---

However, for testing local on a PC from the UnityEditor I would not want the app to leak data into my development PC but rather place it somewhere into e.g. `StreamingAssets` and only in a build use the `persistentDataPath`

```
var folderPath =
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
     Application.persistentDataPath;
#else
     Application.streamingAssetsPath;
#endif
```